# Estoy creando un crud y al momento de actualizar los datos me manda el siguiente error

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el error que me manda:

> Warning:Cannot modify header information -headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:/xampp/htdocs/crud/Ajustes.php:1) in
>   C:/xampp/gtdocs/crud/Ajustes.php on line 168

En la linea de código 168 esta este **header**:

```
header("Location:editar.php");
```

Comment: Y qué archivo estás queriendo abrir? Ajustes.php? Publicá el código de los archivos.